# Div Moving position and z index

Tags: javascript, css, position, z-index, css-animations

Hope someone can help me, I don't know where to look it up

I'm trying to do an `onclick` event that will change the position of 3 `Div`s.

The DIVS are placed like on a hoizontal circle, which means the one in the middle should be `z-index: 1`

left and right `z-index: -1`
`onclick`, the left should slide to the middle and change `z-index`
right go to the left and middle to the right.

How can I try to do that?
Started like this, but will not change position correctly.
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2kca8cc/3/)

code snippet:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < (threeleft-50)){

  var plus = (i)%2; 

  three.style.left    = (threeleft-i)+'px';
  two.style.left      = (twoleft+plus)+'px';
  one.style.left      = (oneleft+plus)+'px';
  i++;
}
```

Also still need a little of animation if there is a better way to do that, let me know

Thanks so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that during the `while` the screen is not updated so you will only see the final position and not the animation. Then the `plus = i%2` will always return 0 or 1. so that is what gets added to the `two` and `one` positions. (*you most likely need `var plus = i/2;` there*)

In general i would use CSS for positioning/animating (*through transitions*) the elements and just changes classes with JS. Much cleaner and more maintainable.

```js
function goleft() {
  var one = document.querySelector('.pos-one'),
    two = document.querySelector('.pos-two'),
    three = document.querySelector('.pos-three');

  one.classList.remove('pos-one');
  one.classList.add('pos-two');

  two.classList.remove('pos-two');
  two.classList.add('pos-three');

  three.classList.remove('pos-three');
  three.classList.add('pos-one');
}

function right() {
  var one = document.querySelector('.pos-one'),
    two = document.querySelector('.pos-two'),
    three = document.querySelector('.pos-three');

  one.classList.remove('pos-one');
  one.classList.add('pos-three');

  two.classList.remove('pos-two');
  two.classList.add('pos-one');

  three.classList.remove('pos-three');
  three.classList.add('pos-two');
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

.pic {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#one {
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  background-color: blue;
}

#three {
  background-color: green;
}

.pos-one {
  z-index: 150;
  top: 50px;
  left: 250px;
}

.pos-two {
  z-index: 50;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50px;
}

.pos-three {
  z-index: 50;
  top: 40px;
  left: 450px;
}

#bot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pic pos-one" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="pic pos-two" id="two">2</div>
  <div class="pic pos-three" id="three">3</div>
  <div id="bot">
    <button onclick="goleft()">left</button>
    <button onclick="right()">right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```